# Subsurface mod doing odd things to mesh

Tags: modeling, modifiers

Hey can anyone tell me whats going on with my mesh? I added a subsurface mod and the entire thing became pinched in weird places and not at all like the what i intended.  Im trying to model the top part of this image but when I add the subsurf mod it becomes too smooth and weird when it needs to be hard surface.  Any idea? Ive attached the blend file also

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/101170/weird-blender-subsurface-glitch/101174#101174

Comment: Your topology is not good. You should try and have faces that have four vertices.

Comment: Avoid using ngons (faces with more than 4 vertices).