# Make head if my figure smoother

Tags: objects, subdivision-surface

I need to make this head smoother. I am already using subdivion surface 3 on whole object.

I found here and try select head and use shade smooth.

Head stil had that visible lines and just not look smooth.

[image]
[image]
Here is file, I hope I upload it right.

Comment: please show a screenshot of your mesh, it must be bad, or share your file

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1684/what-is-the-technical-difference-between-an-ngon-and-a-bunch-of-triangles/ and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3199/weird-deformation-between-large-ngon-and-edge-ring

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens due to the n-gon face on top of the head of your figure. They don't subdivide well, so you get some kind of wavy surface.
To avoid this, you should try to keep quads (faces with four vertices) wherever possible.

That means that you shoud put some additional edge loops there, e.g. like that:
[image: added edge loops]
What I did was extruding the top face and scaling it down, then repeating the same thing, so that the inevitable transition from quads to one ngon happens in the small area in the middle.

Cheers