# Subdivision modifier difficulties

Tags: subdivision-surface

I'm trying to smoothen the rough edges of my model using the subdivision modifier but it's being very difficult. Some places it goes all wonky and I don't seem to have any control over it. What am I missing? How to I get rid of those crevasses?

[image]
[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3199/why-does-subsurf-modifier-cause-weird-deformation-at-the-end-of-a-cylinder/

Comment: Adding to @DuarteFarrajotaRamos's link, you have tons of N-gons in your geometry. Try to make them all nice quads by adding edge loops and try to keep the amount of triangles low and only where you can't avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

It's because of the topology. For Sub-d modeling topology is very relevant (wheras if you model hard surface without sub-d, just using bevels, you can get away with N-gons in flat surfaces). You probably used a boolean there, and joined pieces toghether, but you have to clean that topology and make it all quads before using subdivision otherwise all sorts of artifact like those or worse will occur.
You can see in that model, the only part where there seems to be a smooth angle is where the edge lines connect with the ones from the other plane (in the rest of the model they are discontinuous).
Before you retopologyse I'd recommend you watch a couple tutorials on retopology so you don't have to retopolgise it several times like I did when I was starting.

Now if I can give you a couple tips for sub-d modeling is just keep it as simple as possible and let the sub-d add the rest of the geometry. That mesh there, besides needing to do away with all those loose vertices it is also too dense for that shape. You can always control the way it subdivides with creases, but all of those edge lines there on what seems to be a flat surface, they don't help but actually complicate. Just stick with what changes the outline (ant the least possible, ie. an exagon makes a circle when subdivided) and do away with the rest. Also use control edges and avoid poles on skewed surfaces (You'll need some poles to increase/decrease mesh density on certain places but make it on the flatest areas possible).